How to correct xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint slot 2 ep 1
I have a Raspberry Pi4B running Ubuntu 22.04LTS server 64-bit and a generic USB Audio Adapter connected to one of the USB ports. I also have mpg123 player installed.
I use the command below to play a very short mp3 file (test file with 4 words):
$ mpg123 -o alsa:hw:1,0 test.mp3
It plays Ok but I get the following error through the console port every time mpg123 plays:
[  299.764064] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint slot 2 ep 1
[  299.772401] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: @000000044fb0a930 00000000 00000000 0e000000 02028001

What is it and how do I correct it?.
Below is the list from command "aplay -l":
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.
